# Price level changes: accounting for new products

Tags: inflation

I'm looking for a method to integrate new products into the calculation of price level changes.

Assume a market for a single good, all of which are substitutes. For all goods in the market, we know the prices and quantities sold. However, we have no information about the quality of each product, and have no way to compare products against each other.

In the absence of new products, we could calculate price level changes between two periods by summing, across all products, the change in product price multiplied by each products' market share:

$$
PLC = 
\sum_{product=1}^n \left(\frac{p_{1} - p_{0}}{p_{0}}\right) 
* 
\left(\frac{q_{1}}{Q_{1}}\right)
$$

where $Q_{1}$ is the sum of all sales in period 1.

Given the following sales figures:

**Period 0**

| Product | Price | Items sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 10 |
| B | 2 | 6 |
| C | 3 | 4 |

**Period 1**

| Product | Price | Items sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 10 |
| B | 3 | 2 |
| C | 3 | 6 |

Price level change between periods 0 and 1 would be given by product B alone, and be equal to:

$$
\left(\frac{3 - 2}{2}\right) 
* 
\left(\frac{2}{18}\right)
= 0.055
$$

Assume instead that in period 1, a new product enters the market, and that sales figures in period 1 are given by:

**Period 1**

| Product | Price | Items sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 10 |
| B | 3 | 1 |
| C | 3 | 3 |
| X | 6 | 6 |

Is there a reasonable way to account for the entry of product X? For product X, could one substitute in a value for $p_{0}$ (for example the market average/median price) to account for the fact that prices paid in this market have clearly gone up?

Comment: Inflation is usually understood as the change of the *general price level* rather than the change in product prices weighted by market share. Check out the formulas for CPI and GDP deflator.

Comment: Thanks @HerrK. Maybe I should not have used the word inflation, but rather refer to price level changes. I'll edit the question accordingly. If you have thoughts beyond your comment above, I'd be happy to hear them.

Comment: I would suggest to have a look at the Consumer Price Index Manual at https://doi.org/10.5089/9781484354841.069, 1.131 to 1.142 discusses some of the issues arising from new products and how to deal with them. For example, is X a revolutionary good or just an improvement of an existing one?